# How to create a tail recursion for this in Haskell [T = 1/x + x/2 + 3/x +x/4 + ...]

Tags: haskell

I tried this

```
    recursion n x = if mod n 2 == 0 
                      then x/n + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1) 
                      else n/x + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1)
```

but there's a problem

```
 Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 18 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

how to solve that problem and what's wrong with my code?

Comment: you should not mix `mod` and `/` without converting to what you really want

Comment: btw: even after fixing (see questin below) - it'll not be tail-recursive - do you actually care?

Comment: This function does not terminate even if the types are fixed. The series as written diverges. `**(-1)` does not correspond to anything in the description.

Answer (score 4):

The `mod n 2 == 0` constraints `n` to be an [**`Integral`** type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral), but then you use `x/n` and since the `(/)` function has signature [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-), this means that `x` and `n` have the same [**`Fractional`** type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional). It makes no sense that a number type is both `Integral` and `Fractional`.

You can work with `fromIntegral` to convert `n` to a `Fractional` type:

```
recursion :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b
recursion n x = if mod n 2 == 0 
                  then x/fromIntegral n + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1) 
                  else fromIntegral n/x + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1)
```

Another problem with your function is that there is no *stop condition*. You need to add an extra clause:

```
recursion :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b
recursion n x
  | n <= 0 = 0
  | mod n 2 == 0 = x/fromIntegral n + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1) 
  | otherwise = fromIntegral n/x + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1)
```

This then produces for example:

```
Prelude> recursion 10 2
0.3481658094621751
```

Comment: Is this tail recursive ?   It looks like there's still more work to be done after the recursive call gets made.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already explained the errors here. A nice Haskell way to solve this problem is as follows:

```hs
import Data.List (scanl')

getNthApprox n x = approximations !! n where
    approximations = scanl' (+) 0 $ fmap term [1..]
    term n = if n `mod` 2 == 0
             then x / fromIntegral n
             else fromIntegral n / x
```

It turns out that due to the magic of laziness, `getNthApprox` works out to have the same performance characteristics as tail recursion. This is because elements of `scanl' (+) 0 $ fmap term [1..]` are constructed only as they are needed in the calculation of `approximations !! n`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not an answer but this one would correspond more closely to the caption:

```hs
tSumToN :: (Enum a, Fractional a) => Int -> a -> a
tSumToN n = sum . take n . tSeq

tSeq :: (Enum a, Fractional a) => a -> [a]
tSeq x = 
  interleave odds evens
  where
    odds = [ o / x | o <- [1,3..]]
    evens = [ x / e | e <- [2,4..]]
    interleave [] _ = []
    interleave (y:ys) zs = y:interleave zs ys

example :: Double
example = tSumToN 4 1.1
```

btw: this one does obviously not converge mathematically so it seems rather pointless to take partial sums - but hey whatever

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are seeing are because the compiler can't figure out the argument types for the function.  Adding type constraints to the function takes care of this:

```haskell
recursion :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b 
recursion n x = if mod n 2 == 0 
                then x/fromIntegral n + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1) 
                else fromIntegral n/x + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1)
```

Now the function compiles but will not terminate because there is no check for a terminal condition (`n==0`).  To fix this, add the check.

```haskell
recursion :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b 
recursion n x   | n == 0 = 0.0
                | mod n 2 == 0 = x/fromIntegral n + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1) 
                | otherwise = fromIntegral n/x + (recursion (n-1) x)**(-1)
```

Now the function will terminate with an answer but the answer does not match the formula stated in the question title.  To fix this, remove the **(-1) .

```haskell
recursion :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b 
recursion n x   | n == 0 = 0.0
                | mod n 2 == 0 = x/fromIntegral n + (recursion (n-1) x)
                | otherwise = fromIntegral n/x + (recursion (n-1) x)
```

Now the function returns the correct values.  The following main program verifies that this is the case:

```haskell
main :: IO ()
main = do 
          print $ recursion 1 1.0
          print $ 1/1.0

          print $ recursion 2 1.0 
          print $ 1/1.0 + 1.0/2

          print $ recursion 3 1.0
          print $ 1/1.0 + 1.0/2 + 3/1.0

          print $ recursion 4 1.0 
          print $ 1/1.0 + 1.0/2 + 3/1.0 + 1.0/4
```

The function returns the correct values but is not tail recursive.   As a first step in making it tail recursive, reduce it to a single recursive call.  To do this note that the terms in the formula come in pairs and group them together along with a `n-2` recursion.   The function now will only work for even `n` but that can be patched up later.

```haskell
recursion :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b 
recursion n x   | n == 0 = 0.0
                | otherwise = fromIntegral (n-1)/x + x/fromIntegral n + (recursion (n-2) x)
```

The function still is not tail recursive because there is additional processing (additions) done after the recursive call.  One way to work around this is to introduce an accumumator argument to hold incomplete values.

```haskell
recursion :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b -> b
recursion n x acc  | n == 0 = acc
                   | otherwise = recursion (n-2) x (fromIntegral (n-1)/x + x/fromIntegral n + acc)
```

As a final step a wrapper function can be introduced to handle odd values of `n` and to hide the accumulator argument.  Use an appropriately modified version of the above test code to verify.

```haskell
no_recursion :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b 
no_recursion n x = if mod n 2 == 0 
                   then recursion n x 0.0
                   else fromIntegral n / x + recursion (n-1) x 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you apparently meant was

```
recursion n x = if snd (properFraction (n / 2)) > 0   -- isOdd
                then x/n + recursion (n-1) (x**(-1))
                else n/x + recursion (n-1) (x**(-1))
```

but there's two problems here. First of all *correctness*, since you start from `n`th term and go back to `0`th, but use `x` as the starting value always, whereas it differs depending on whether `n` is even or odd. We fix problems like this by moving the actual work into the inner, "worker" function, and fixing the starting value of the iteration.

Second problem is that it is *not* *tail recursive*. We fix problems like that by introducing an accumulating parameter to the inner, "worker" function. One tool to fix two problems!

```
-- T = 1/x + x/2 + 3/x + x/4 + ...

recursion :: RealFrac a => a -> a -> a
recursion n x = if snd (properFraction (n / 2)) > 0   -- n is odd
                then goOdd  n 0
                else goEven n 0
  where
  goOdd  n acc     = goEven (n-1) (acc + n/x)
  goEven n acc 
       | n <= 0    = acc
       | otherwise = goOdd  (n-1) (acc + x/n)
```

Now it's correct, and tail recursive as you wanted.